# Integer overflow in differential_drive wheel encoders?

Tags: navigation, odometry, encoder, rosserial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm reading a sensored brushless motor's [tri-phase hall encoders](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Eee323/index.php?p=lab7a) in an effort to get odometry on my robot.

I get six increments for one motor turn. The motor runs at something like 17000rpm at max speed. If I track the encoders with an std_msgs/Int16 message, as expected from the [differential_drive](http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive) package, I will get an integer overflow after only about 300 ms...

I'll be using [rosserial_arduino](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino) on an [Arduino Micro](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMicro) with interrupt driven software.

Is there an alternative package I could use? Maybe something that tracks the relative change of the encoder counter instead of its absolute value?

Cheers
Laurenz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224123/integer-overflow-in-differential_drive-wheel-encoders?/) by [lalten](https://answers.ros.org/users/25550/lalten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2016-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [package wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive) it says;

> wheel_low_wrap (int, default: 0.3 *
> (encoder_max - encoder_min) +
> encoder_min
>
> wheel_high_wrap (int, default: 0.7 *
> (encoder_max - encoder_min) +
> encoder_min
>
> If a reading is greater than wheel_high_wrap and the next reading
> is less than wheel_low_wrap, then the
> reading has wrapped around in the
> positive direction, and the odometry
> will be calculated appropriately. The
> same concept applies for the negative
> direction.

Therefore it seems like it can handle wrap around.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3